# Where to place ChromeDriver while executing tests through selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I installed selenium and downloaded chromedriver.exe
When i run the code in my gitbash terminal then its working but not working when I run a python script in visual studio code.

On internet it say to put the file in the path but i don't know much about it. Where should i place the chromedriver.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is **Anywhere**.

---

Add the path for where you put the driver by command line:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\WHERE_I_PUT_THEDRIVER\
```

Or

In Your Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> System -> Advanced System Setting -> Advanced -> Environment Variable -> System Variable -> [Choose] Path -> [Click] Edit

So when you import it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

wd = webdriver.Chrome()
```

---

Or, if you prefer not to add new path,

```
from selenium import webdriver

__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
#__location__ is current file location
driver_loca = os.path.join(__location__, 'bin/chromedriver.exe')
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= driver_loca)
```

Comment: I add the command line for set path and says that a new directory is created. But still it didnt work. I can use webdriver in gitbash command line but can't use it in visual studio code. Is the problem in visual studio code settings?

Comment: @SultanMorbiwala, What kind of error do you have? Red underline in pylint?

Comment: I says 'executable file may have wrong permission'. my code is driver = webdriver.Chrome() and created a path like you said above

Comment: and visual studio code terminal says 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home'

Comment: Problem solved, i directly chromedriver from pip. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SultanMorbiwala, pip works because your system already has `C:\Python\` as path. `set PATH=%PATH%;` has some problem, I am testing. The path is not actually added with this command.

Answer (score 1):

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\littl\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

Answer (score 0):

> Short answer is **anywhere**

As per your question you can put the *ChromeDriver* **anywhere** within your local system and when you initialize the *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* pass the *Key* **executable_path** mentioning the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* as follows:

- Windows OS style

  ```
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  ```
- Linux OS style

  ```
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
  ```
- MacLinux OS X style

  ```
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
  ```

**Note**: Avoid accessing *ChromeDriver* placed in shared drives.

Answer (score 0):

I use Anaconda for which i placed chromedriver.exe in the following

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts